# Using p-input-icon-left with p-autocomplete

Tags: html, angular, primeng

Is there any way to use the PrimeNG input field icon stuff with an `p-autocomplete` field?

E.g. something similar to this

```html
<span class="p-input-icon-left">
    <i class="pi pi-search"></i>
    <input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="value1" placeholder="Search">         
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

just add

```
i {
  z-index: 1;
}
::ng-deep .p-autocomplete .p-inputtext {
  padding-left: 28px;
}
```

worked for me